# CSS Formatting text alignment within a <div> element

Tags: html, css

I am basically trying to align text within a `div` element to format an interactive SI unit chart. I want to create two columns of content on the left and right side of the divide. The left has prefixes (centi-, milli-, etc.) and the right has their corresponding values (10^-2, 10^-3 etc.). When hovering cursor over an element in the chart, I want that entire horizontal section of the chart to change in background color (so the horizontal section with both centi- and 10^-2 for example). I tried subdividing the `div` element but was unsuccessful because the columns will not align properly and the prefix and its corresponding value are on different lines. An example of the code is below. Help

```html
<body>
<style>
.hover:hover {
 background-color:yellow;
 }
</style>
 <div style="with:300px;border:solid;position:absolute;margin-left:100px;margin-top:200px;">
 <div class="hover">
 <div style="width:100px;text-align:left">
 centi-
 </div>
 <div style="width:100px;text-align:right">
 10^-2
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="hover">
 <div style="width:100px;text-align:left">
 milli-
 </div>
 <div style="width:100px;text-align:right">
 10^-3
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="hover">
 <div style="width:100px;text-align:left">
 micro-
 </div>
 <div style="width:100px;text-align:right">
 10^-6
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Scroll down to see the result of the code snippet. My bad

Comment: make them inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.hover div {
  display: inline-block
}

.hover:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div style="with:300px;border:1px solid;">
  <div class="hover">
    <div style="width:100px;text-align:left">
      centi-
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px;text-align:right">
      10^-2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hover">
    <div style="width:100px;text-align:left">
      milli-
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px;text-align:right">
      10^-3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hover">
    <div style="width:100px;text-align:left">
      micro-
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px;text-align:right">
      10^-6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Div has `display:block` by default. Make those divs `display:inline-block`.